# Why isn't everthing in a superposition state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, measurement-problem, superposition, decoherence

I know that a superposition is a state in which there are 50% and 50% (other % also) chances of two things to happen so why am I not in a superposition state?
Example, I am at rest and i now choose to be in motion so there can be a 50-50% chance of myself that i will be walking or running, so I think I am in a superposition state so can't we say that everything in this universe is in a superposition state?

Comment: [Decoherence](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=decoherence)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validity of naively computing the de Broglie wavelength of a macroscopic object](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57390/)

Comment: Hi Bhavesh, I've linked a possible duplicate, but there are many closely related questions on the site. See the search I've linked in my first comment.

Comment: Of *course* you're in a superpositioned state when you're at rest (or when you're running, or any other time).  The state of rest is the sum of the states $A=(1/2)rest+(1/2)running$ and $B=(1/2)rest-(1/2)running$.

Comment: Even if a suitable operator with that spectrum existed (it doesn't have to), at room temperature your coherence length would be much smaller than the size of a nucleus.

Comment: One possible interpretation of quantum mechanics is that everything actually *is* (and stays) in a state of superposition, you just don't notice because no measurement can tell the difference between being in a superposition sate and a "non-superposition state". This is (equivalent to) the many worlds interpretation.

Comment: I just want to mention that only two different eigenstates of a measurement can be in superposition.