# waves particle duality of human body

Tags: wave-particle-duality

De Broglie stated electrons can travel as particles and waves. Electrons show its waves properties when they can diffract through a carbon layer. So, I am not sure about his statement which human also can diffract through a gap.

Comment: In theory yes, if you don't mind working with odds of winning the lottery 115 weeks in a row, buying 1 ticket a week.   In practice, a single particle can do things like pass through a barrier or interact with itself, but the odds of a collection of particles all doing the same thing and coming out of it having the same structure on the other side of the gap - it gets unlikely really really fast as you add complexity.

Comment: Wave particle duality is an old model that one should not use any more than one would use epicycles to describe planetary motion. Having said that, the simple diffraction theory would only apply for a system without internal degrees of freedom and under the assumption that all the mass is concentrated in a volume much smaller than the diffraction volume. Neither is true for a human, so the answer is a clear no.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validity of naively computing the de Broglie wavelength of a macroscopic object](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57390/)