# de Broglie's Hypothesis

Tags: diffraction

I've recently understood de Broglie's hypothesis, and I understand that a necessity for electrons to show diffraction is that the size of the aperture they pass through must be of the order of their de Broglie wavelength. So exactly what would happen if (if) I were to walk through a door of a size of the order of my de Broglie wavelength? If a number of people of the same order of masses did so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validity of naively computing the de Broglie wavelength of a macroscopic object](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57390/)

Comment: @JohnRennie It's interesting, that there isn't need in the maximum size of the aperture particles pass through of the order of their de Broglie wavelength. Any sharp edge influenced the particles in a way that behind the edge where will appear intensity distributions. Another amazing point is, that the amplitude for such waves as well as for electromagnetic radiation is unknown. The minum aperture depends from the wavelength, but who can number out the amplitude?

Answer (score -1):

Your de Broglie's wavelength is (assuming your weight is around 70 kg and you are moving 1 m/s)
$\lambda = h/mv = 6.6\times10^{-34}/70 \approx 10^{-35} $ which is less then the [Plank length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_length) - the least sensible distance. And this is much less than the diameter of protons/neutrons so even decomposed on elementary particles you wouldn't fit into such a door.