# Dual nature of matter

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, wave-particle-duality, duality

DeBroglie's hypothesis suggests that every body has particle-like and wave-like properties (which may or may not be observable). This means that I as a person walking down the road with a velocity $v$ would exhibit both particle and wave-like properties (though my wave-like properties would be negligible). My question is: what kind of a wave do I describe? A *standing* wave or a *travelling* wave?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validity of naively computing the de Broglie wavelength of a macroscopic object](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57390/)

Comment: @JohnRennie My question concerns what type of a wave I describe **not** the problem of computing the deBroglie wavelength for a system of particles.

Comment: Please note that this doesn't have anything to do with symmetry (either in the QFT sense or in the everyday language sense), saying so is just poetical. Also, you have wave-like properties regardless of whether you move down the road or elsewhere.

Comment: I guess I'd rather delete the question instead of being repeatedly told that it's a _duplicate_.

Comment: I agree with the OP: This is a quite different question than the one linked as a duplicate.

Comment: To all those who have voted to close this question, did you even care to open the suggested link to verify whether my question is actually _duplicate_?

Comment: @KunalPawar  as much as I know it would be a probability amplitude wave with negligible wavelength. Standing waves are for the particles that are bound , like an electron in a shell. Had you been trapped in box it would have been a standing wave ( with even lesser wavelength)

Answer (score 3):

Most likely a wave-packet. But from a QM point of view an incoherent mixture of wave packets (mixed state).