# Can massive objects behave as a wave?

Tags: wave-particle-duality

I have used the word *object* but I'd be referring to *particles* as in the context, the objects would be comparatively very small.

Consider the de Broglie's equation: 
$$ \lambda = \frac{h}{mv}  \implies v = \frac{h}{m\lambda}$$

A particle having zero initial velocity would require an impulse of $mv$ to get the required velocity.
According to Newton's law of gravitation: 
$$ F = \frac{G Mm}{r^2} $$
To get the required impulse, we can have the Gravitational force work for a short interval of time $t$ i.e. $$J = \frac{GMm t }{r^2} $$
To get the required $\lambda$ for the particle :
$$mv = J$$
$$\implies \frac{h}{\lambda} = \frac{GMmt}{r^2}$$
$$\implies r= \sqrt\frac{GMmt\lambda}{h} $$

For $M=1$Kg, $m = 1$Kg, $t = 1$s, $\lambda = 650$nm
 $r$ comes out to be $2.56 \times 10^{8} $ m

So, at the the given conditions would the wave nature dominate to a mass of 1 Kg ?
What would be the consequences ? Would everyday objects behave like a wave ? Would our perception of massive objects change ?

**EDIT:**
The question was marked duplicate of [Validity of naively computing the de Broglie wavelength of a macroscopic object](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57390/validity-of-naively-computing-the-de-broglie-wavelength-of-a-macroscopic-object) which it certainly is not.
This question is about the consequences of a massive object (Such as a human being) behaving like a wave of a significant wavelength unlike the mentioned question which asks the *validity* of de Broglie equation on non-fundamental (many-body) object.

Comment: This question seems to assume massive objects would have regular everyday size. I don't know what I might have been thinking 2 years back but even very small particles could have a mass of 1kg and not be everyday object. 
Further, _everyday objects_ are made up of many particles. Assuming them to be one particle is faulty to begin with.