# Can de Broglie wavelength of a particle be smaller than its size?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavelength

Can de Broglie wavelength of a particle be smaller than its size?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible. The momentum of the particle dictates its de-Broglie wavelength, not its dimension. Hence, large particles often have a smaller de-Broglie wavelength than their dimension. [It has also been experimentally observed in this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms1263) (more papers exist but this one deals with very large particles).

[There is another interesting discussion on the validity of computing the de-Broglie wavelength of a macroscopic object on PhysicsSE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57390/validity-of-naively-computing-the-de-broglie-wavelength-of-a-macroscopic-object).

Comment: A very common and well studied example is nuclear fusion of heavy ions. The de Broglie wavelength corresponds to the center of mass motion.