# Wave particle duality

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wave-particle-duality

Can someone please explain wave particle duality for large bodies? Why don't large bodies exhibit wave like nature for example if I am walking with some momentum, the wavelength associated with me is $h/p$ what does this mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validity of naively computing the de Broglie wavelength of a macroscopic object](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57390/)

Answer (score 0):

de Broglie wave length is defined as : $$\lambda _{B}={\frac {h}{p}}$$
So if for example your mass is 60 kg and you are moving with a sports car with a speed of 200 km/h, then *your* de Broglie wave-length [would be](https://calistry.org/calculate/deBroglieEquation) on the order of $10^{-37}$m. No physical length can be smaller than [Plank length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_length) which is $1.616\;229\times 10^{-35}\ \mathrm {m}$. Thus de Broglie wave lengths for macroscopic big objects means nothing.

Comment: Yes but what when I move a cricket ball slowly I can vary the speed of the cricket ball of I make it let's say 10^-24 then ?

Comment: Some distance per second which is smaller or comparable to electron diameter ? Such technology doesn't exists which would let to control macroscopic object speed with **microscopic** precision comparable to electron diameter. Even if let's say _hypothetically_ you would invent such thing, then according to Heisenberg uncertainty principle setting such high precision on macroscopic body speed in effect will make it's _position unknown_. So it's NOT doable.

Comment: Ok what if I am sitting on my table does that not make my momentum zero

Comment: Plugin zero momentum into the formula and you will get $\lambda _{B} = \infty$ - infinite de Broglie wavelength. If you can't detect wave **periodicity** in space - then this is not a wave at all. Pretty much like circle with infinite radius is not circle at all. Any system with _infinite_ parameter value is un-physical and makes no sense. The only exception to this rule is a _singularity_ in black hole center. However this can also mean that as for now simply we don't have good `quantum gravity` theory which would resolve infinity issues at black hole center