# What would happen if my body de Broglie wavelength is significantly large?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavelength

I have a question that what would the world be, if matter de Broglie wavelength was large?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validity of naively computing the de Broglie wavelength of a macroscopic object](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57390/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, that only means -- for a particle -- that its momentum is small, so it is "very susceptible to quantum effects", and thus must be described by Quantum Mechanics.

Reinterpreting your question, if everything in the world had a large de Broglie wavelength, everything should be described *exclusively* through quantum mechanics, and classical laws (e.g. Newton's laws) would be unapplicable -- which is not the case --.

I think that beyond that, your question goes beyond what answer you might find in this SE forum, where we focus more in real physics than in big "What if" questions. If this didn't answer your question, please edit it to be more precise in what you want to find out, and I will move my answer to the comments ;)

Comment: Thanks,  I just asked it out of curiosity

Comment: Did it solve your question?